Help for Openstack
i have try to install below command received where i have found sunbeam-controller password.
cmd : juju show-controller sunbeam-controller
output : please enter password for openstack.protectionsheild.io on sunbeam-controller:
Thanks

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
